# Multiple showings of AngularJS Unit Tests in VS2015 Test Explorer with Chutzpah and Jasmin

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I wrote some Unit Tests for my AngularJS stuff and use Chutzpah to run the tests in VS. That works like a charm but every test shows up 3 times in VS Test Explorer. Any idea why? My chutzpah.json looks like this:

```
{
  "References": [
     { "Path": “Path of needed file” },
     { "Path": “Path of needed file” },
     { "Path": “Path of needed file” },
     { "Path": “Path of needed file” }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your actual Chutzpah.json file contents?
Also, if you have a real repo to link to that could be helpful also.

Comment: I found the mistake in the weekend. I still had a html site for running the tests without Chutzpah. Chutzpah found the Tests on its own and toke them again from the html.

Comment: Sknecht: Please post your comment as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in the weekend. I still had a html site for running the tests without Chutzpah. Chutzpah found the Tests on its own and toke them again from the html.